# MPMoviePlayer start video only after buffering half the video file

Tags: iphone, ios, video, buffer, mpmovieplayer

In my iphone app,I have used MPMoviePlayer.
The video start playing after small part of buffer is over and fastly it becomes buffer again.Thus the video interrupts many times while watching

Is there any remedy for this ??

How can I set,start playing only after half part of video is got buffered ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a property `shouldAutoplay` of MPMoviePlayer. The default value of this property is `YES` change it to `NO` and call `play` method after a delay. It will not exactly half buffer your video but it will definitely improve usability. You can also set `MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming` as the value for `movieSourceType`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the total playback duration, that is the duration of the video, then you can schedule a timer that periodically compare two property of MPMoviePlayerController: `playableDuration` and `duration`.

```
if (player.duration > 0.0 && player.playableDuration > 0.0)
{
    if (player.playableDuration >= player.duration / 2)
    {
        // playable duration is half of the player duration.
        // That is half of the video is buffered.
    )
}
```